# How to convert this tuple to a dict in python

Tags: python

I have the following tuple in Python.

```
('"https://www.dzone.com": "Z"\n\n', '')
```

I need to convert this to a dictionary in Python as follows.

```
{'URL': 'https://www.dzone.com', 'Rank': 'Z'}
```

How to do this in Python.

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. First of all, your tuple has several syntax errors (unclosed single-quote, colon where a comma should be). Are you looking to (1) recognize urls and "ranks" somehow (like with a regex), (2) call the first item a url and the second item a rank (and ignore the third item??) and your primary problem is in making the dictionary, or something else entirely? Also, welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only the first element of the tuple. Split this element at the `': '` and you'll get a list with the two parts you need.

```
data = ('"https://www.dzone.com": "Z"\n\n', '')[0].split(': ')
```

Now construct your dictionary by using `strip` to remove the unwanted characters at the beginning and end of each string.

```
result = {'URL': data[0].strip('"'), 'Rank': data[1].strip('"\n')}
```